# How to express (in)equality just like a native

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, negation

I would like to say...

> *My Mom did not get angry as much as my Dad did.*

...but I want the sentence to also convey that I had expected my Mom to be *more* angry (not less) than my Dad.

How can I say this in natural English?

Comment: Are you talking about the intensity of their anger, or about how often they got angry?

Comment: If you want a *phrase*: `Contrary to expectation, my Mom did not get as angry as my Dad`. If you want a *word*, `Surprisingly` or `Unexpectedly`

Comment: @JohnFeltz about intensity

Comment: I edited the title of your question, because it's about how to express equality or inequality, not literally how to say the word "equality".  Please feel free to change it if you think I changed the meaning too much!

Comment: It depends on what the source of the expectation as. Is this a cultural perception that women are supposed to be angrier than men? Or are you saying that based on the temper of your father, people who knew your father would expect your mother to also be an angry person?

Comment: @mstorkson
No I just use Mom and Dad as an example if you want you can change their position in my sentence. There is no pre-assumption.

Comment: @Darshan Baral

It makes sense But there is a very handy way in my mother tongue to describe this situation. Then I am looking for something like that in English

Comment: **Felt like Mom could've got much as angry as Dad did** Something like this?

Comment: @hyeganeh, What is your mother tongue? And can you please describe the "handy way"? That would be helpful to answer your question and also for me to know a little about your mother tongue.

Comment: @SovereignSun
No, the second comment makes more sense but I think it is not as handy as my expectation.

Comment: @DarshanBaral
My lang. is Persian. When I use handy what comes to my mind in this case is a sentence which is a pattern or template in English lang. For example The more .... , the more .....   is a pattern for which we have an equivalent template in Persian.

Answer (score 6):

When you're trying to illustrate the difference between what you expected and what actually happened, you need to use words like "but", "however", "contrary", or "unexpectedly" to provide that contrast.

> I thought my mom would be angrier than my dad, **but** it was the other way around.
>
> **Contrary** to my expectations, my dad was angrier than my mom.

Answer (score 0):

How about "in spite"?

In spite of my expectations, Mom was not as angry as my dad. Or perhaps *despite*?

> de·spite
>   dəˈspīt/
>   preposition
>   1.
>   without being affected by; in spite of.
>   "he remains a great leader despite age and infirmity"
>   synonyms:   in spite of, notwithstanding, regardless of, in the face of, for all, even with
>   "despite his lack of enthusiasm, Zachary had a pretty good time"

Answer (score 0):

I thought Mom would probably kill me, but it was Dad who took me to the woodshed! And that's the truth!

Comment: Hi cidchase, could you please elaborate? It would help the OP understand better. Cheers !